# open csv.reader multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to open a csv.reader twice in the same function.
I used 2 "with" blocks and named the variables differently:

```
def make_template(input_file):

import csv

with open(input_file,'rt') as input_file:        
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    ## code    

with open(input_file,'rt') as inputf, open('template.csv','w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
    reader1 = csv.reader(inputf, delimiter='\t')
    ## code
```

I'm getting an error-

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Hila

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
with open(input_file, 'rt') as inputf:
```

because it overwrites `input_file` with the file object, so the later 
`open` gets a file object as input, not a string.

This will solve your issue:

```
import csv

with open(input_file,'rt') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter='\t')
    ## code

with open(input_file,'rt') as inputf, open('template.csv','w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
    reader1 = csv.reader(inputf, delimiter='\t')
    ## code
```

As a general rule, I like to seperate the notion of *filenames* from the notion of *file objects*. This avoids these kind of issues and arguably is more readable anyway. 
So I propose to use the following variable naming:

```
import csv

with open(input_filename,'rt') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    ## code

with open(input_filename,'rt') as input_file, open('template.csv','w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
    reader1 = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    ## code
```

Comment: you are completely right! thanks!